# How Can I Get My Play! 2.0 Application to Automatically Compile Protocol Buffers?

Tags: git, scala, heroku, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a few `.proto` files for my project that I used the generated Java source for. I would like Play to automatically compile and include these files during project compilation.

Ideally, I would keep my `.proto` files within the `app` directory as follows:

```
<play root>/
  app/
    protobuf/
      myfile.proto
    controllers/
      Application.scala
  ...
```

A few requirements are as follows:

- The generated source should *not* be included in git
- Heroku *must* be able to compile the protobufs during deployment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [sbt-protobuf](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-protobuf). You will need to configure a few files as follows (using sbt 0.11 or greater):

#### project/plugins.sbt

```
resolvers += "gseitz@github" at "http://gseitz.github.com/maven/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-protobuf" % "0.2.2")
```

#### build.sbt

```
// must be at top of file

import sbtprotobuf.{ProtobufPlugin=>PB}

seq(PB.protobufSettings: _*)

javaSource in PB.protobufConfig <<= (sourceManaged in Compile)
```

This configuration will expect protobufs in `app/protobuf` and place them in the managed (not version controlled) source directory.

***Warning*** - Do *not* give your protobuf files the package name `messages`, it will interfere with Play and you will get i18n errors all over the place.